# Cannot start TFS Build service: Error 1227

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-server

When I try to start the TFS 2008 Build service on the port 9191 I get the following error message:

> *Windows could not start the Visual
>   Studio Team Foundation Build service
>   on Local Computer.*
>
> *Error 1227: The network transport
>   endpoint already has an address
>   associated with it.*

If I use another port it works, but I need it to be the default, 9191.

I will appreciate any help!

---

### Update:

I have tried by removing every binding to the port 9191 that the following command shows:

```
netsh http show uracl
```

To remove the bindings I used the following command:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://xxxx:9191/Build/v2.0/AgentService.asmx/
```

Once I removed the bindings, the service was able to start, but the BS web service were not available from the outside, this is because of the removed bindings. I ran the following command to reserve the endpoint again:

```
wcfhttpconfig.exe reserve Domain\ServiceAccount https://xxxx:9191/Build/v2.0/AgentService.asmx/
```

But then, the service is unable to start again. The same error message is displayed as before.

The log trace of TFSBuildService contains the following message:

```
TF224000: The Visual Studio Team Foundation Build service failed to start because another application is already using the address http://xxxx:9191/Build/v2.0/AgentService.asmx.
Exception Message: HTTP could not register URL http://+:9191/Build/v2.0/AgentService.asmx/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. (type AddressAlreadyInUseException)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a build agent defined on that server using the standard port.  Each build agent *has* to have it's own port, otherwise it wouldn't know where to listen.

Comment: I have been playing around with lot of stuff, I may changed something that ended using the port 9191 but there isn't another build agent running on the same box and I couln't find what is using the port.

Comment: Using the command **netsh http show uracl** I found what endpoints are using the port and remove them using **netsh http delete urlacl url=**, but once I reconfigured the BS, the same error is shown when starting the service.

Comment: I wonder if the build service is looking at something within the TFS configuration, and that you have some sort of default agent still defined to TFS (even if it isn't defined to Windows).  Out of curiosity, why does this need to be on the default port?

Comment: I have configured the TFSBuildService.exe.config file to use the port 9191 and SSL, I have the certificate in place and added it to the ip 0.0.0.0:9191 with netsh too. I need to use port 9191 because of a constraint of the company running the AppTier (TFS).

Comment: Interesting,  I just read something where someone was getting the same issue due to ssl not being  configured correctly.  Google TFS 9191 and ssl.  The article was on msdn.

Comment: Check here, maybe it will lead you in a good direction:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/1b8e7e9f-e0f2-4d26-b089-e82444252eaf

Comment: You should change default port in tfsbuild.exe.config file, this may help a little bit.